# How can I invert the areas covered by my diffuse pattern?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, node-editor

I'm new to Blender, so I'm sorry if some of this is ridiculously wrong. 
I've been trying to place a diffuse texture over a bump map, reflection map and a displacement modifier not taken from the same place as the diffuse texture. To be more clear, I've been trying to get a pattern taken from one picture to realistically be placed onto the bump map, reflection map and displacement of a different picture.

This is what I have so far.
[image]

I want the inverse of this outcome but more exaggerated so that the chipped parts won't have any of the pattern.

[image]

I'm thinking maybe I need to edit my starting pics in photoshop so it's more of what I want to begin with, but I was hoping there was an easier way just in Blender.

( I would have put more pictures to explain more clearly, but I don't have enough "reputation")

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse of this outcome"? Probably adding *Color > Invert* node connected between your mask and **Mix Node** can help?

Comment: Or you could perhaps just swap mix node shader inputs, so the fac should act reversed?

Comment: By inverse I mean that I want the pattern to only show up on the parts that are raised instead of being covered by them. Thanks for the suggestions.